# Diferencias entre el contexto por medio de la sentencias "class" y "function" en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, function, class

Tengo entendido que en JavaScript todo es un objeto y la sentencia class como function son formas alternas de crear objetos en JavaScript.

Estoy aprendiendo sobre como usar el contexto, cuando en una clase saco una función de uno de sus miembros su contexto es undefined.

```
class a{
  had(){
    console.log(this);
  }
}
console.log("class a-----");
w = new a();
w.had();//object a
q = w.had;
q();//undefined
```

Cuando saco una función de un objeto creado a partir de una función su contexto es window.

```
function AA(){
  this.k = 10;
  this.p = function(){console.log(this);}
}

d = new AA();
d.p();//Object AA
l = d.p;
l();//window
```

si ambas sentencias crean objetos entonces ¿porque el contexto es diferente?¿Son diferentes tipos de objetos?. Si pueden proporcionarme recursos para poder profundizar en esto se los agradecería mucho. Gracias.